# error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct }' has no member named 'body'というエラーの回避方法

Tags: esp32

現在、Visual Studio Code と platformio でLVGLというESP32のTFTディスプレイにGUI画面を作成するサンプルプログラムのビルドを勉強しています。

たくさんのエラーが発生しています。エラー内容を見ていると

```
error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct }' has no member named 'body'
```

このエラーが多発していることが分かったのですが、このエラーの回避方法を教えてください。

**エラー内容**

```
> Executing task in folder ESP32Test: C:\Users\kmaeh\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe run <

Processing esp32dev (platform: espressif32; board: esp32dev; framework: arduino)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif32/esp32dev.html
PLATFORM: Espressif 32 (1.12.4) > Espressif ESP32 Dev Module
HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash
DEBUG: Current (esp-prog) External (esp-prog, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa)
PACKAGES:
 - framework-arduinoespressif32 3.10004.200129 (1.0.4)
 - tool-esptoolpy 1.20600.0 (2.6.0)
 - toolchain-xtensa32 2.50200.80 (5.2.0)
LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> http://bit.ly/configure-pio-ldf
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 43 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
Dependency Graph
|-- <drv>
|   |-- <lv_arduino> 3.0.1
|-- <lv_arduino> 3.0.1
Building in release mode
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\src\main.c.o
src\main.c: In function 'my_tab_test':
src\main.c:105:23: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lv_theme_alien_init' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   lv_theme_t *theme = lv_theme_alien_init(90, NULL);
                       ^
src\main.c:105:23: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
src\main.c:106:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lv_theme_set_current' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   lv_theme_set_current(theme);
   ^
src\main.c:110:37: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lv_tabview_get_style' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   pStyle_tv_btn_rel = (lv_style_t *)lv_tabview_get_style(tabv_obj, LV_TABVIEW_STYLE_BTN_REL);
                                     ^
src\main.c:110:68: error: 'LV_TABVIEW_STYLE_BTN_REL' undeclared (first use in this function)
   pStyle_tv_btn_rel = (lv_style_t *)lv_tabview_get_style(tabv_obj, LV_TABVIEW_STYLE_BTN_REL);
                                                                    ^
src\main.c:110:68: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
src\main.c:111:20: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
   pStyle_tv_btn_rel->body.padding.left   = LV_DPI / PADDING_RATE;
                    ^
src\main.c:112:20: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
   pStyle_tv_btn_rel->body.padding.right  = LV_DPI / PADDING_RATE;
                    ^
src\main.c:113:20: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
   pStyle_tv_btn_rel->body.padding.top    = LV_DPI / PADDING_RATE;
                    ^
src\main.c:114:20: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
   pStyle_tv_btn_rel->body.padding.bottom = LV_DPI / PADDING_RATE;
                    ^
src\main.c:115:20: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
   pStyle_tv_btn_rel->text.font = &lv_font_roboto_12;
                    ^
src\main.c:115:35: error: 'lv_font_roboto_12' undeclared (first use in this function)
   pStyle_tv_btn_rel->text.font = &lv_font_roboto_12;
                                   ^
src\main.c:118:26: error: 'lv_style_plain' undeclared (first use in this function)
   lv_style_copy(&indic, &lv_style_plain);
                          ^
src\main.c:119:8: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
   indic.body.main_color = lv_color_hsv_to_rgb(90, 80, 87); //color for theme alien
        ^
src\main.c:120:8: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
   indic.body.grad_color = lv_color_hsv_to_rgb(90, 80, 87); //color for theme alien
        ^
src\main.c:121:8: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
   indic.body.padding.inner = LV_DPI / 16;
        ^
src\main.c:122:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lv_tabview_set_style' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   lv_tabview_set_style(tabv_obj, LV_TABVIEW_STYLE_INDIC, &indic);
   ^
src\main.c:122:34: error: 'LV_TABVIEW_STYLE_INDIC' undeclared (first use in this function)
   lv_tabview_set_style(tabv_obj, LV_TABVIEW_STYLE_INDIC, &indic);
                                  ^
src\main.c: In function 'create_home_condition_tabview':
src\main.c:152:25: error: 'lv_style_pretty_color' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_style_copy(&style, &lv_style_pretty_color);
                         ^
src\main.c:154:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style.body.main_color = LV_COLOR_GRAY; // Line color at the beginning/ gray
       ^
src\main.c:155:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style.body.grad_color = LV_COLOR_WHITE; // Line color at the end/ gray
       ^
src\main.c:156:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style.body.padding.left = 5; // Scale line length/
       ^
src\main.c:157:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style.body.padding.inner = 8; // Scale label padding/
       ^
src\main.c:158:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style.body.border.color = LV_COLOR_GRAY; // Needle middle circle color/
       ^
src\main.c:159:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'line'
  style.line.width = 3;
       ^
src\main.c:160:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'line'
  style.line.color = LV_COLOR_RED; // Line color after the critical value/
       ^
src\main.c:161:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  style.text.color = LV_COLOR_GRAY; //lv_color_hex3(0x333);
       ^
src\main.c:162:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  style.text.font = &lv_font_roboto_12;
       ^
src\main.c:162:21: error: 'lv_font_roboto_12' undeclared (first use in this function)
  style.text.font = &lv_font_roboto_12;
                     ^
src\main.c:163:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  style.text.opa = LV_OPA_COVER; // no transparent
       ^
src\main.c:171:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lv_gauge_set_style' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  lv_gauge_set_style(gauge1, LV_GAUGE_STYLE_MAIN, &style);
  ^
src\main.c:171:29: error: 'LV_GAUGE_STYLE_MAIN' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_gauge_set_style(gauge1, LV_GAUGE_STYLE_MAIN, &style);
                             ^
src\main.c:176:32: error: 'lv_style_plain' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_style_copy(&label_style1, &lv_style_plain);
                                ^
src\main.c:177:14: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  label_style1.text.font = &lv_font_roboto_28;
              ^
src\main.c:177:28: error: 'lv_font_roboto_28' undeclared (first use in this function)
  label_style1.text.font = &lv_font_roboto_28;
                            ^
src\main.c:178:14: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  label_style1.text.color = LV_COLOR_WHITE;
              ^
src\main.c:181:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lv_label_set_style' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  lv_label_set_style(label1, LV_LABEL_STYLE_MAIN,  &label_style1);
  ^
src\main.c:181:29: error: 'LV_LABEL_STYLE_MAIN' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_label_set_style(label1, LV_LABEL_STYLE_MAIN,  &label_style1);
                             ^
src\main.c:186:14: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  label_style2.text.font = &lv_font_roboto_12;
              ^
src\main.c:187:14: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  label_style2.text.color = LV_COLOR_WHITE;
              ^
src\main.c:198:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'line'
  style_arc.line.color = LV_COLOR_GRAY;
           ^
src\main.c:199:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'line'
  style_arc.line.width = 4;
           ^
src\main.c:201:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lv_obj_set_style' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  lv_obj_set_style(arc1, &style_arc);
  ^
src\main.c:208:12: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'line'
  style_arc2.line.color = lv_color_hex(0x00EBC1); // lv_color_hsv_to_rgb(90, 80, 87);
            ^
src\main.c:209:12: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'line'
  style_arc2.line.width = 8;
            ^
src\main.c:218:14: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  label_style3.text.font = &lv_font_roboto_28;
              ^
src\main.c:219:14: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  label_style3.text.color = LV_COLOR_WHITE;
              ^
src\main.c: In function 'create_gps_condition_tabview':
src\main.c:235:25: error: 'lv_style_pretty_color' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_style_copy(&style, &lv_style_pretty_color);
                         ^
src\main.c:237:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style.body.main_color = LV_COLOR_GRAY; // Line color at the beginning/ gray
       ^
src\main.c:238:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style.body.grad_color = LV_COLOR_GRAY; // Line color at the end/ gray
       ^
src\main.c:239:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style.body.padding.left = 2; // Scale line length/
       ^
src\main.c:240:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style.body.padding.inner = 8; // Scale label padding/
       ^
src\main.c:241:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style.body.border.color = LV_COLOR_GRAY; // Needle middle circle color/
       ^
src\main.c:242:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'line'
  style.line.width = 2;
       ^
src\main.c:243:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'line'
  style.line.color = LV_COLOR_GRAY; // Line color after the critical value/
       ^
src\main.c:244:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  style.text.color = lv_color_hex3(0x333);
       ^
src\main.c:246:7: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  style.text.opa = LV_OPA_COVER;
       ^
src\main.c:256:29: error: 'LV_GAUGE_STYLE_MAIN' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_gauge_set_style(gauge1, LV_GAUGE_STYLE_MAIN, &style);
                             ^
src\main.c:293:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style_led.body.radius = LV_RADIUS_CIRCLE;
           ^
src\main.c:294:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style_led.body.main_color = lv_color_hsv_to_rgb(90, 80, 87);
           ^
src\main.c:295:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style_led.body.grad_color = lv_color_hsv_to_rgb(90, 80, 87);
           ^
src\main.c:296:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style_led.body.border.width = 0;
           ^
src\main.c:297:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style_led.body.shadow.width = 0;
           ^
src\main.c:313:12: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style_led2.body.main_color = LV_COLOR_YELLOW;
            ^
src\main.c:314:12: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style_led2.body.grad_color = LV_COLOR_YELLOW;
            ^
src\main.c:327:12: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style_led3.body.main_color = LV_COLOR_ORANGE;
            ^
src\main.c:328:12: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style_led3.body.grad_color = LV_COLOR_ORANGE;
            ^
src\main.c:345:26: error: 'lv_style_pretty' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_style_copy(&bar_bg, &lv_style_pretty);
                          ^
src\main.c:346:8: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  bar_bg.body.main_color = lv_color_hex(0x012E43);
        ^
src\main.c:349:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  bar_indic.body.main_color = lv_color_hsv_to_rgb(90, 80, 87); //color for theme alien
           ^
src\main.c:350:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  bar_indic.body.grad_color = lv_color_hsv_to_rgb(90, 80, 87); //color for theme alien
           ^
src\main.c:351:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  bar_indic.body.shadow.width = 0;
           ^
src\main.c:352:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  bar_indic.body.padding.top = 0;
           ^
src\main.c:353:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  bar_indic.body.padding.bottom = 0;
           ^
src\main.c:354:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  bar_indic.body.padding.left = 0;
           ^
src\main.c:355:11: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  bar_indic.body.padding.right = 0;
           ^
src\main.c:362:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lv_bar_set_style' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  lv_bar_set_style(bar1, LV_BAR_STYLE_BG, &bar_bg);
  ^
src\main.c:362:25: error: 'LV_BAR_STYLE_BG' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_bar_set_style(bar1, LV_BAR_STYLE_BG, &bar_bg);
                         ^
src\main.c:363:25: error: 'LV_BAR_STYLE_INDIC' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_bar_set_style(bar1, LV_BAR_STYLE_INDIC, &bar_indic);
                         ^
src\main.c:376:12: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  bar_indic2.body.main_color = LV_COLOR_YELLOW; //color for theme alien
            ^
src\main.c:377:12: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  bar_indic2.body.grad_color = LV_COLOR_YELLOW; //color for theme alien
            ^
src\main.c:398:12: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  bar_indic3.body.main_color = LV_COLOR_ORANGE; //color for theme alien
            ^
src\main.c:399:12: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  bar_indic3.body.grad_color = LV_COLOR_ORANGE; //color for theme alien
            ^
src\main.c:422:32: error: 'lv_style_plain' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_style_copy(&label_style3, &lv_style_plain);
                                ^
src\main.c:423:14: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  label_style3.text.font = &lv_font_roboto_16;
              ^
src\main.c:423:28: error: 'lv_font_roboto_16' undeclared (first use in this function)
  label_style3.text.font = &lv_font_roboto_16;
                            ^
src\main.c:424:14: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  label_style3.text.color = LV_COLOR_WHITE;
              ^
src\main.c:427:29: error: 'LV_LABEL_STYLE_MAIN' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_label_set_style(label3, LV_LABEL_STYLE_MAIN,  &label_style3);
                             ^
src\main.c:432:14: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  label_style4.text.font = &lv_font_roboto_28;
              ^
src\main.c:432:28: error: 'lv_font_roboto_28' undeclared (first use in this function)
  label_style4.text.font = &lv_font_roboto_28;
                            ^
src\main.c: In function 'create_message_frame':
src\main.c:443:34: error: 'lv_style_pretty' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_style_copy(&(obj->area_bg), &lv_style_pretty);
                                  ^
src\main.c:444:14: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  obj->area_bg.body.main_color = lv_color_hex(0x012E43);
              ^
src\main.c:445:14: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  obj->area_bg.body.grad_color = lv_color_hex(0x012E43);
              ^
src\main.c:450:26: error: 'LV_BAR_STYLE_BG' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_bar_set_style(area1, LV_BAR_STYLE_BG, &(obj->area_bg));
                          ^
src\main.c:465:37: error: 'lv_style_plain' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_style_copy(&(obj->style_line), &lv_style_plain);
                                     ^
src\main.c:466:19: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'line'
  (obj->style_line).line.color = lv_color_hex(0x02CDFF); //frame color
                   ^
src\main.c:467:19: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'line'
  (obj->style_line).line.width = 2;
                   ^
src\main.c:468:19: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'line'
  (obj->style_line).line.rounded = 1;
                   ^
src\main.c:472:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lv_line_set_style' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  lv_line_set_style(line1, LV_LINE_STYLE_MAIN, &(obj->style_line));
  ^
src\main.c:472:27: error: 'LV_LINE_STYLE_MAIN' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_line_set_style(line1, LV_LINE_STYLE_MAIN, &(obj->style_line));
                           ^
src\main.c: In function 'create_battery_condition_tabview':
src\main.c:485:34: error: 'lv_style_pretty' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_style_copy(&style_batt_bar, &lv_style_pretty);
                                  ^
src\main.c:486:16: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style_batt_bar.body.main_color = lv_color_hex(0x005F7B);
                ^
src\main.c:487:16: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  style_batt_bar.body.grad_color = lv_color_hex(0x005F7B);
                ^
src\main.c:490:16: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  batt_bar_indic.body.main_color = lv_color_hex(0x02CDFF);
                ^
src\main.c:491:16: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  batt_bar_indic.body.grad_color = lv_color_hex(0x02CDFF);
                ^
src\main.c:492:16: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  batt_bar_indic.body.shadow.color = LV_COLOR_RED;
                ^
src\main.c:493:16: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  batt_bar_indic.body.shadow.width = 0;
                ^
src\main.c:494:16: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  batt_bar_indic.body.padding.top = 0;       /*Set the padding around the indicator*/
                ^
src\main.c:495:16: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  batt_bar_indic.body.padding.bottom = 0;
                ^
src\main.c:496:16: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  batt_bar_indic.body.padding.left = 0;
                ^
src\main.c:497:16: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'body'
  batt_bar_indic.body.padding.right = 0;
                ^
src\main.c:501:29: error: 'LV_BAR_STYLE_BG' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_bar_set_style(batt_bar, LV_BAR_STYLE_BG, &style_batt_bar);
                             ^
src\main.c:502:29: error: 'LV_BAR_STYLE_INDIC' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_bar_set_style(batt_bar, LV_BAR_STYLE_INDIC, &batt_bar_indic);
                             ^
src\main.c:508:33: error: 'lv_style_btn_rel' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_style_copy(&batt_lv_style, &lv_style_btn_rel);
                                 ^
src\main.c:509:15: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  batt_lv_style.text.font = &lv_font_roboto_28;
               ^
src\main.c:509:29: error: 'lv_font_roboto_28' undeclared (first use in this function)
  batt_lv_style.text.font = &lv_font_roboto_28;
                             ^
src\main.c:512:15: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  batt_lv_style.text.color = lv_color_hex(0x00D2FF); //LV_COLOR_CYAN;
               ^
src\main.c:513:16: error: 'lv_style_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'text'
  batt_lv_style2.text.color = lv_color_hex(0x00D2FF); //LV_COLOR_CYAN;
                ^
src\main.c:518:39: error: 'LV_CONT_STYLE_MAIN' undeclared (first use in this function)
  lv_label_set_style(label_batt_level, LV_CONT_STYLE_MAIN,  &batt_lv_style);
                                       ^
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\lib70e\drv\disp_spi.c.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\lib70e\drv\ili9341.c.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\lib70e\drv\xpt2046.c.o
In file included from lib\drv\xpt2046.c:9:0:
lib\drv\xpt2046.h:19:23: fatal error: lvgl/lvgl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
lib\drv\disp_spi.c:17:23: fatal error: lvgl/lvgl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
lib\drv\ili9341.c: In function 'ili9341_init':
lib\drv\ili9341.c:107:31: error: 'ILI9341_BCKL_ACTIVE_LVL' undeclared (first use in this function)
  gpio_set_level(ILI9341_BCKL, ILI9341_BCKL_ACTIVE_LVL);
                               ^
lib\drv\ili9341.c:107:31: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\FrameworkArduino\esp32-hal-touch.c.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\FrameworkArduino\esp32-hal-uart.c.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\FrameworkArduino\libb64\cdecode.c.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\FrameworkArduino\libb64\cencode.c.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\FrameworkArduino\main.cpp.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\FrameworkArduino\stdlib_noniso.c.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\FrameworkArduino\wiring_pulse.c.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\FrameworkArduino\wiring_shift.c.o
*** [.pio\build\esp32dev\src\main.c.o] Error 1
*** [.pio\build\esp32dev\lib70e\drv\xpt2046.c.o] Error 1
*** [.pio\build\esp32dev\lib70e\drv\disp_spi.c.o] Error 1
*** [.pio\build\esp32dev\lib70e\drv\ili9341.c.o] Error 1
======================================================================================== [FAILED] Took 4.27 seconds ========================================================================================
The terminal process "C:\Users\kmaeh\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe 'run'" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Comment: どのようなプログラムなのかが判りません。エラーメッセージから元のプログラムが何か判る訳もありません。

Comment: https://github.com/bigw00d/esp-idf-littlevgl-sample

Comment: こちらのLVGLのサンプルコードをVScodeのplatformioのプロジェクトに入れてビルドしてみたところ今回のエラーが出ています。
プロジェクトフォルダ内のincludeフォルダに”lv_style_t”に関連するファイルがないか検索してみたのですが、どうやらないみたいです。
これらに関連するファイルをダウンロードできるサイトなどはないでしょうか？